# Disable the ability to automatically add characters IntelliJ IDE

Tags: webstorm

I wanted to disable the ability to add characters in some places. For example, in JavaScript files, when I interplay, I add a + last line, which is not pleasant.

I use WebStorm.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) IntelliJ IDEA is one product; WebStorm -- it's another one. You are using both of them or just WebStorm? 2) Try to explain what the issue you are having one more time -- I do not understand it. Try using images, e.g. this is (image 1) what I have right now.. and this is (image 2) what happens when I do this .. but I want it to be like this (image 3).

Comment: do you mean that an empty line gets automatically added to your file (on saving, etc.)? What is *Ensure line feed at file end on Save* value in **Settings | Editor | General**? If it's not enabled, see if you have any `.editorconfig` files in your project